# Only get part of string in android?

Tags: android, string, url

Okay I wasn't really sure how to word this question, but basically what I want to do is, I got a url from a webView in android, and I need to put part of that url into a string, the url  will look something like this: `http://localhost/?code=4/3pakksajdfASDFwek.4nsKfAYN7XQVshQV0ieZDAp-PrgEcAI` and I only want the part after code=, is that possible? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int start = my_string.indexOf("=");
String suffix = my_string.substring(start + 1);
```

Comment: You should also check that start >= 0, otherwise, if the url does not contain a "=", substring will throw an exception

Answer (score 0):

If other parameters can be on the URL, or code is not always first parameter:

```
String url = "http://localhost/?code=4/3pakksajdfASDFwek.4nsKfAYN7XQVshQV0ieZDAp-PrgEcAI";
String code = url.replaceAll(".*(?:[?]|[&])code=([^&]+)","\1");
```

tests here: http://fiddle.re/nxfv

Answer (score 0):

If you are totally sure the URL never has other form, you can use `indexOf` and `substring`.

Otherwise, it is better if you use [`URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class to extract out the query part of the URL (use [`getRawQuery`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#getRawQuery%28%29) just to be safe), then tokenize it with `split` along `&` character and find the correct key-value pair to obtain the correct value. This method is not as brittle as `indexOf` method above.